# Scrolling menu in c++? how to change if to switch-case?

Tags: c++, scroll, menu

hello i make Scrolling menu in c++

```
do
{
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0)
    {
        pointer -= 1;
        if (pointer <= -1)
        {
            pointer = 6;
        }
        ShowMenu(pointer,Menu);
    }
    else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) != 0)
    {
        pointer += 1;
        if (pointer >= 7)
        {
            pointer = 0;
        }
        ShowMenu(pointer,Menu);
    }
    else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) != 0)
    {
        switch (pointer)
        {
        case 0:
            //do somethink awesome!xD
            break;
        }
    }
    Sleep(150);
}
while(true);
```

but how to change this if
to switch case? Useing GetAsyncKeyState?
i can use somethink like this

```
char button;
switch(button){
case 27: // is escape
//to do
break;
}
```

but i want use GetAsyncKeyState xD

Comment: _"but i want use GetAsyncKeyState"_ Short answer: You can't.

Comment: i must use this? case 27: ......? where i can find all id of key in keyboard?

Comment: You should handle keyboard messages in window procedure. I am not sure what this loop is doing with `Sleep` (is it a separate thread?)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mixing up the console program and the window based program. the "case 27" style is possible for console, but not for window based.

but if you really want to use the switch style, you may try

```
(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0) << 2 + 
(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) != 0) << 1 + 
(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) != 0)
```

Then you may have 8 possible combination in the switch case

By the way, what you did is using a while loop to poll the keystate, which is a CPU monster and waste too much.